# Ubuntu 14.04 won't go past the log in screen; update

Tags: 14.04, nvidia, login, compaq, presario

I loaded Ubuntu on an older laptop with windows vista. I opted for the dual boot. the computer boots to the Grub menu and I pick Ubuntu it loads and goes to the log in screen. I log in and hit enter the screen goes black, a few lines of code pop up then it goes back to the log in screen. this is my first time with Ubuntu. I was able to go into vista fine. I decided to try to re-install Ubuntu thinking that it would overwrite what was on the computer but it just installed a second instance. The same thing happens with the log in screen on either instance and now I can't get into vista. I would like to use Ubuntu on that laptop but how do i get Ubuntu to continue past the login?

I looked at the listings of this being a duplicate question. I changed the install to a solo install of 14.04 Ubuntu. I get to the log in screen and still not able to log in as user or guest. I did ctrl-alt-f1 and logged in on the shell. I can run commands on the shell. I tried the chmod and chown command lines listed on the duplicate. when i shift back to the log in screen still no luck. I tried the install-session and that didn't work. I noticed that when I ran the sudo command the prompt stayed at $ instead of switching to #.

Have there been issues with Unity desktop on an Nvidia video card? what command line sequence do i use to download the Unity desktop with nvidia drivers?

I am using a compaq presario cq60 laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Install the NVIDIA drivers this way :

When login screen appears press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F1</kbd>.
Type in your user name and your password.
Then execute the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-current 
sudo reboot
```

Comment: I tried this route. The apt-get update worked and loaded a bunch of package update.

Comment: the apt-get install returned the following: Reading package lists...done  building dependency tree   reading state information...done    package nvidia is not available but is referred to by another package. this may mean that the package is missing has been obsoleted or is only available from another source.   E: package 'nvidia' has no installation candidate    E: unable to locate package current

Comment: after I posted this i worked some more on it. I decided to wipe the drive and do a total install again. this eliminated solutions I had tried before. immediately after the install I went through these and it worked. i now have a login and desktop. thank you